# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor in Tomcat application after some time

Tags: oracle11g, tnsnames, tns

I'm looking at a web application that's using JDBC Connection to connect to Oracle 11g database (11.2.0). The application works without any issues for some time (about an hour) and then I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I tried restarting Oracle and the Oracle services OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener but the error won't go way. It only goes away after I restart my machine.

I've not changed any database parameters in my Tomcat or Oracle.

Here's my tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

Here's my configuration for JDBC:

```
    String serverName = "localhost";
    String portNumber = "1521";
    String sid = "xe";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
    String username = "xxx";
    String password = "yyy";
```

When "XE" is working properly, if I check lsnrctl status, I can see

```
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Once I get the exception, I do not see instance "xe" when I check lsnrctl status.

I would like to know why I'm getting this exception after some time and how to fix that. If not, how can I get around it without restarting my machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Database URL should be as shown below.

```
// Create DataSource and connect to the local database
ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:5221/orcl");
ods.setUser("HR");
ods.setPassword("hr");
conn = ods.getConnection();
```

Recommendation is to use the long form of connection URL as shown here. 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhost-vip)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))

Also, to verify if the connection URL is correctly formed, get a connection from the SQL developer using the below and test it out.

sqlplus hr/hr@"(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhost-vip)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))"